# swift convenience initializer error

Tags: swift, initializer

I am following the code as suggested in the WWDC on swift initializers. However I see the error "overriding declaration requires an override keyword". 
Any thing I am missing?

```
class Car{
    var paintColour: Colour

    init(colour: Colour){
       self.paintColour = colour;
    }
}

class Colour{

}

class RaceCar: Car {
   var hasTurbo: Bool

   init(colour: Colour, turbo: Bool){
       self.hasTurbo = turbo;
       super.init(colour: colour);
   }

   convenience init(colour: Colour) {
       self.init(colour: colour, turbo: true);
   }

 }
```

However in the above convenience initializer, I see the compiler error "overriding declaration requires an override keyword".

```
class FormulaOne: RaceCar{
   init(color: Colour, hasTurbo: Bool){
       super.init(colour: color, turbo: false);
   }
}
```

What is the reason for this error, when the code is exactly the same as shown in the video from WWDC?

Answer (score 1):

When you inherit from Car class, you inherit his methods, properties and initializers.

this init

```
init(colour: Colour)
```

still implemented in the superclass Car, so you must to write override if you want to change or add more functionality.

In the FormulaOne class, the init function has not the same declaration.

Try to change from

`init(color: Colour, turbo: Bool)`

to

`init(colour: Colour, turbo: Bool)`

The compiler tell you to add `convenience` keyword because in your implementation you call to `self.init` and designated init must call to `super.init` and not to another init in the same class `self.init`

There are two kinds of initilizers in Swift : Designated and Convenience.
Designated init is the major init.
Convenience init is secondary init.

Swift 3 rules about initializers:

1. Designated init must call a designated init from its superclass
2. Convenience init must call another init from the same class
3. Convenience init must ultimately call a designated init.

Swift 3 rules illustrated:

[image: rules illustrated]

Answer (score 0):

`RaceCar` is overriding the initializer

```
init(colour: Colour)
```

provided by its superclass `Car`.

You need to explicitly annotate the method, exactly as the error message is telling you.

```
convenience override init(colour: Colour) { ... }
```